# Context attributes not available in Django template

Tags: python, django, templates, django-queryset

I'm trying to display a specific attribute in a template in Django.  I believe I've passed the correct queryset in the context, but for some reason I'm only able to access the id attribute, and not the title attribute that I need.

Views.py:

```
@login_required
def watchlist_view(request):
    listings = models.WatchedListing.objects.filter(owner = request.user)
    return render(request, "auctions/watchlist.html", {"listings": listings})

@login_required
def add_to_watchlist(request, listing_id):
    listing = models.Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id)
    user = request.user
    currently_watched = models.WatchedListing.objects.filter(owner = request.user)
    if listing in currently_watched.all():
        messages.error(request, "This item is already on your watchlist.")
        return redirect(reverse('listing', args=[listing.pk]))
    else:
        watchlist = WatchedListing()
        watchlist.owner = user
        watchlist.watched_listing = listing
        watchlist.save()
        messages.success(request, "Added to your watchlist!")
        return redirect(reverse('listing', args=[listing.pk]))
```

Models.py:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_bid = models.ForeignKey(Bid, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="start_bid")
    image_url = models.TextField(null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)
    current_bid = models.ForeignKey(Bid, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="current_bid")
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    num_bids = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class WatchedListing(models.Model):
    watched_listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='watched_listings', blank=True, null=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name ='watchlist_owner')
```

watchlist.html:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block title %} Watchlist {% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <strong style="color: red">{{ message }}</strong>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if listings is not None %}
        <ul>
        {% for listing in listings %}
            <a href = "{% url 'listing' listing_id=listing.id %}">
                <li>{{ listing.title }}</li>
            </a>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        No watched listings yet.
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Where I have listing.title in the template, I just get blank space, but the ul bullet list item shows up with a link to the appropriate listing.  Howevever, if I change to listing.id, the id attribute will show up.  What am I doing wrong to get the listing's title to show up?

Comment: Are you sure you have a title set for that listing? Do other attributes like `category` show, or just id?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting objects of `WatchedListing` in the template. So to have title there, you need to refer it through the `ForeignKey` field as

```
<li>{{ listing.watched_listing.title }}</li>
```

Comment: This was it!  Thank you so much, didn't realize offhand I was passing an unintended type of object to the template.